# Delete file interrupting an OutputStream

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I'm running a thread in my app that exports an image. The process requires writing into an OutputStream.

When my app suddenly closes using the Back Button, the file keeps existing with 0 bytes.
Is there any way to close an OutputStream file while exiting the app?

I've tried the following code but the file doesn't get deleted. My guess is that the file is being written in that moment and it can't delete itself.

```
public void onDestroy() {
        if (export){ // this boolean tells me if the thread is running
            file.delete();
        }
    super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you click on back button Android doesn't call onDestroy(), but call **onPause()** and **onStop()** 
try to put your code inside those methods

Answer (score 0):

use `onPause()`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      if (export){ // this boolean tells me if the thread is running
      file.delete();
     }
      super.onPause();
    }
```

`onDestroy` calls when the activity destroys,not when you go back!

Comment: when touching the back button my app exits... I've never overriden it. Anyway, my problem is that when my app suddenly exits and the export process was still working, the stream can only be flushed but isn't closed, so the file can't be deleted...